# How to replicate and merge String in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to implement a function where you input a list of Strings i.e.

```
["test1","test2"]
```

and it will return a replication of the list which will turn it into

```
["test1test1","test2test2"]
```

I have tried to implement it using replicate, but that turns it into

```
[["test1","test2"],["test1","test2"]].
```

Comment: Hint: what operation should you apply to *every* element. How do you *map* element from one list to another one?

Comment: `map (join (++))`

Comment: `((<>) <*> id) <$>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `(\x -> x++x)` duplicates a single string, what you need is

```
map (\x -> x++x)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `replicate`, you'll need to `concat`enate all the strings in each inner list:

```
-- Create n copies of the string, then concatenate them
dupStr :: Int -> String -> String
dupStr n = concat . replicate n

-- Same thing on each element of a list of strings
dupStrs :: Int -> [String] -> [String]
dupStrs n = map $ dupStr n

-- Your function specifically
dup2 :: [String] -> [String]
dup2 = dupStrs 2

dupStr 3 "a" == "aaa"
dupStrs 2 ["t1", "t2"] == ["t1t1", "t2t2"]
dup2 ["test1", "test2"] == ["test1test1", "test2test2"]
```

This works for any number of repetitions.

Comment: Thanks so much! just what I needed, been trying to figure out how to do it for days, the closest I ever got was rep n = concatMap (replicate n)

Comment: days? Join the #haskell IRC room and get some feedback sooner, it really helps when learning.

Comment: ah yes, I'm a bit of a noob, literally only started getting into it last week @ThomasM.DuBuisson

Answer (score 1):

You can do this visually, without thinking verbally about it:

```
g :: [[t]] -> [[t]]
g xs = [ [c | y <- [x,x], c <- y]  | x <- xs ]
```

Now that we have it working, we can recognize that it is equivalent to

```
     = [  concat   [x,x]           | x <- xs ]
     = [  concat  (replicate 2  x) | x <- xs ]
     = [ (concat . replicate 2) x  | x <- xs ]
     = map (concat . replicate 2)         xs
```

which is plenty verbal now. Whatever style is easier for you.

`(f . g) x = f (g x)` is *function composition*, piping the output of a function on the right into the function on its left, as input. Some like it *point-free* style,

```
g :: [[t]] -> [[t]]
g = map (concat . replicate 2)
```

("point" refers to `xs` in the definition of `g xs = ...`; a definition without arguments is known as being in point-free style).

Well, actually, `concat [x,x]` is just `x ++ x = (++) x x = join (++) x` and so we could even write

```
  = map (join (++))
```

but this style takes getting used to. It is also no good if we want to concatenate three, or even more copies of  string, which is very easy to arrange for with the above style, even defining a new function,

```
g :: Int -> [[t]] -> [[t]]
g n = map (concat . replicate n)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple list comprehension works here:

```
map_twice xs = [x ++ x | x <- xs]
```

Comment: there really is no need for `zip`. referencing the same variable twice is quite all right.

Comment: @WillNess yep, I totally agree with you on that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

For some fanciness with applicative style you may also do as;

```
g :: [String] -> [String]
g = zipWith (++) <$> id <*> id

Prelude> g ["test1","test2"]
["test1test1","test2test2"]
```

Comment: or even `join (zipWith (++))`. :)